# How can I start a cron job to pause vlc at certain times

Tags: bash, cron, vlc

I would like to know how I can use bash to pause vlc at certain times on ubuntu 20.04 running native.I imagine cron but can't get it started and I don't really know any text editors ?

Comment: `crontab -e` uses whatever the default editor is set to.  Once you add something to it, then cron starts.  Have you been able to pause VLC with a terminal command while it has been playing?  If so, then you would add that command to a script that could be called by cron, or you can add the full path to the cron itself.

Comment: I have used this,dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2   org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause
and it works just not as cron and I have restarted cron,so its not that

Comment: crontab -l shows 30 1 * * * /dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2   org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try doing the command as `30 1 * * * /usr/bin/dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause`  If that doesn't work, put that command into a script file, then have cron call the script file.  Also, your pause will only work at 1:30 am.  Do you want it to pause like every 30 minutes?  Every 30 minutes passed the hour?  How are you trying to get it to run?

Comment: I would like it to run every day at 1:30,but I don't know scripting or how to point cron to call the script file,can't you explain this command with myrootcron.sh.

Comment: Could you perhaps give me some pointers on how the script should look ?

Comment: A script would be any filename you wanna call it, say `pause_vlc`, then add in a couple of lines.  The first line should be the interpreter that is `#!/bin/bash` that tells it it is going to use bash as the interpreter.  Then add in the line that does the pausing:  `dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause`  And that is the whole script.  Then in cron you make an entry like `30 1 * * * /path/to/script/pause_vlc`  That's it.

Comment: One other thing, you will need to make the script executable.  `chmod +x pause_vlc`